# Distribution of number of references to other object in an object

Tags: graphs, memory-management, garbage-collection

I been thinking about an improvement to a garbage collector (details not important for this question) and wished to know how often does a object have no reference to other objects.  Clearly this will depend on the language.

Many people must have research this and published the data, yet I can't come up with the correct words to type into Google.

Comment: I don't know either but maybe you can just experiment this somehow. You may choose random code samples from github on a specific topic. Then you can run this on a environment that you build and calculate how often it happens.

Comment: How is this a computer _science_ question? Obtaining these statistics seems tp be a trivial (?), if bothersome, technical task.

Comment: @Raphael I am hoping it has been studied and published for a set of representatives workloads, hence it is a question about computer science literature.